# How can I create a mean based on a bounding box from another column?

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 dataframes with thousands of data points:

```
lat    lon   v1
41.57 -88.11 11
41.58 -88.12 12
42.57 -89.11 55
41.55 -88.31 12

lat    lon   v2
41.57 -88.41 77
41.58 -88.12 56
42.57 -89.11 73
41.55 -88.61 14
```

And I want to:

- Read each Lat-Long combination in Dataframe 1
- Create a square bounding box
- Search all the Lat-Long combinations in that bounding box in Dataframe 2
- Find a mean of v2 in that bounding box and add it to corresponding row in Dataframe 1

I have got this far to write for a single (latval,lonval):

```
library(geosphere)
spatialmean<-function(latval,lonval,distance){
  coords <- c(lonval, latval)
  ne.coords <- c(destPoint(p = coords, b = 90, d = distance)[1],
                 destPoint(p = coords, b = 0,  d = distance)[2])

  sw.coords <- c(destPoint(p = coords, b = 90, d = -distance)[1],
                 destPoint(p = coords, b = 0,  d = -distance)[2])
  lon1<<-sw.coords[1] #Lon of the left side of the box
  lat1<<-sw.coords[2] #Lat of the bottom side of the box
  lon2<<-ne.coords[1] #Lon of the right side of the box
  lat2<<-ne.coords[2] #Lat of the top side of the box
  df2temp<<-subset(df2, lon>=lon1 & lon<=lon2 & lat>=lat1 & lat<=lat2)
  meantemp<<-mean(df2temp$v2)
}

spatialmean(latval=42, lonval=-71,distance=5000)
```

How can I insert the logic of using lat-long combinations from DF1 and insert it back? I don't know how to pass rows as function arguments.

Comment: First, what is your function `destPoint`? Also, it seems like all you really need to do is use the `apply` family of functions (probably mapply) to apply your function over all the rows of df1.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give the library. Updated now. Destpoint basically calculates great circle distance. I am not very familiar with the apply functions. Hence, I am writing it using a for loop. But if you could help with the apply function, I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is

```
df1$meanval <- mapply(FUN = spatialmean, latval = df1$lat, 
                      lonval = df1$lon, distance = 5000)
```

However, I don't think this will be faster than a for loop.  If speed is key, I would add the tag `data.table` to your question, as there is almost certainly a faster way to do this in data.table, but I'm not proficient enough with it to show you that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use actual distance instead of a top heavy square, I would use another function in the geosphere package to find distances. Your squares will have overlapping areas and include distances greater than 5000 in your mean calculations.

```
# sample data with extra row to understand distances row/column
df1 <- data.frame(lat = c(41.57,41.58,42.57,41.55,41.55),
    lon = c(-88.11,-88.12,-89.11,-88.31,-88.31),
    v1 = c(11,12,55,12,12))

df2 <- data.frame(lat = c(41.57,41.58,42.57,41.55),
    lon = c(-88.41,-88.12,-88.11,-88.61),
    v2 = c(77,56,73,14))

# set max distance
maxdist <- 5000

# calculate all distances and check if within limit
distances <- distm(x = df1[ ,c('lon','lat')],y = df2[ ,c('lon','lat')])
withindistance <- distances < maxdist

# grab all v2 based on df1 and calculate the mean. returns NaN if no points within distance
df1$df2mean <- apply(withindistance,1,function(x,funv2){
  mean(funv2[x])
},funv2 = df2$v2)

# or the apply like most would write it. either apply works
df1$df2mean <- apply(withindistance,1,function(x){
  mean(df2$v2[x])
})
```